# функция давления кирпича пирамиды

Tags: алгоритм, математика, любой-язык

Есть двумерная пирамида из кирпичей. Вес 1го - 1 кг, давит равномерно на 2 под ним по 0.5кг.
То есть, если на верхний давит +100 кг, тогда под ним на каждый будет (100+1)/2 кг - на нижний давит пол веса каждого над ним.

1,0=.5 2,0=.75 2,1=1.5 3,0=.875 3,1=.2.125

Как вычислять давление на любой из них, указывая позицию, например, к4-2, к8-4 ... к(рядСверху,номерСлева) - как функция с 2 параметрами, возвращающая вес?

Думал, pяд*.5 + (pяд-1)/2 или 1*(c+1) / 2*p + 1*c / 2*p, разные другие варианты, но никак не могу подобрать точный. (желательно на java)

Comment: "подобрать"? - сумма геометрической и арифметической прогрессий

Comment: Вопрос изложен конечно не совсем  ясно.  Нужно стараться, чтобы догадаться о чем речь.  Реально , для пирамиды нагрузки не  будут равномерны, так как для таких конструкций  нагрузка на каждый элемент  зависит от того, насколько он удален от центра. Но если допускать, что нагрузка равномерная, то эта задача решается легко.  Не понятен также формат вывода   к4-2,  ...  Тут 4 это ряд сверху,  а 2 это нагрузка на кирпич?

Comment: @CodeGust, возможно это ложная идея, но циферки в вашей пирамиде довольно симметричны и похожи на треугольник паскаля, я не силен в математике, но возможно стоит попробовать решить задачу не через рекурсии, а через биномиальные коэф-ты, я не силен в этой теме, но можно копнуть глубже

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему не воспользоваться рекурсией? Значения веса, номер ряда и номер кирпича в ряду вставляйте какие вам надо:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float weight = 1; //вес кирпча
    int row = 5;      //номер ряда начиная с 1 с верху
    int num = 3;      //номер кирпича слева (или с права, как больше нравится) с 1
    System.out.println(pressueOnBrick(row, num, weight));
}

//давление на один кирпич
public static float pressueOnBrick(int row, int num, float weight) {
    return pressue(row, num, weight) - weight;  //давление оказываемое на один кирпич = полное
                                                //давление которое оказывает кирпич минус вес кирпича
}

//полное давление оказываемое кирпичём (включая свой вес)
public static float pressue(int row, int num, float weight) {
    //в ряду не может быть кирпичей с номером меньше 1 и больше чем номер ряда(число кирпичей в ряду = номеру ряда)
    if (num < 1 || num > row) {
        return 0;
    }

    //давление которое оказывает кирпич равно сумме веса кирпича и половине веса кирпичей которые давят на него
    //слева и справа
    return weight + (pressue(row - 1, num - 1, weight) + pressue(row - 1, num, weight)) / 2;
}
```

Валидация вводимых значений на вашей совести.

Comment: Потому, что это алгоритм экспоненциальной сложности. Как минимум, нужно сохранять ранее подсчитанные веса в массив, и пере-использовать их при повторных запросах... получим O(n^2) , хотя можно и O(1).

Comment: Какое это имеет отношение к постановке задачи?

Comment: контрольные значения:1,0=.5 2,0=.75 2,1=1.5 3,0=.875 3,1=.2.125

Comment: Не знаю какая у вас система координат в пирамиде но у меня если брать верхний ряд из одного кирпича как 1 и далее вниз там где 2 второй ряд 3-третий и так далее и считать в ряду с 1 кирпича, то получается: 1-1 = 0 (верхний кирпич, на него ничего не давит), 2-1 = 0,5, 3-1=0,75, 4-1=0,875, 4-2=2,125, 25-14=20,660532. Если я правильно понимаю, то у вас нумерация рядов и позиций кирпичей в ряду начинается с 0, приведенное рекурсивное решение легко адаптировать под это.

Comment: точно, спасибо! да, с 0 начало должно быть. только вот 323,157 ( =306.487...) заглючивает выполнение.

Comment: а не подскажете, почему, если брать больше 35,35, програма начинает "думать" дооолгие минуты, так, что результата не дождешься? вроде, в коде нет ничего ресурсоемкого, но тем более 323,144 не должешься...

Comment: @CodeGust См. первый комментарий. Для более быстрого решения можно просто заполнять таблицу сверху вниз.

Comment: @MBo, рекурсивное решение действительно ресурсоемкое, но уж больно заманчивое, а при постановке задачи про сложность алгоритмов речи не шло. А так, да проще просчитывать пирамиду сверху в низ и все результаты буферизировать, а при следующем запросе если запрашиваемое значение выше основания в буфере, то доставать готовое, а если ниже, то не рассчитывать с верху, а с низа пирамиды в буфере и закатывать рассчитанные значения опять же в буфер, наращивая готовые результаты, а как буфер организовать это уже дело десятое.

Comment: @Евгений Глушков Собственно, автор и условий применения не ставил. Нужно ли много запросов делать и т.д. Это уже в комментариях всплыло про координаты в сотнях. Кстати, для двух внешних рядов формулы в явном виде получаются, а дальше я сбился.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
int main()
{        
    unsigned ranks{};
    std::cin >>ranks;  // общее количество рядов
    double weight{};
    std::map<unsigned, double> loads;
    unsigned k{1};
    for (; k <= ranks; ++k) {
        loads.insert(std::make_pair(k, weight));
        weight = (weight + 1)/2;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "вводим нужный ряд: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> k;
    std::cout << "нагрузка для кирпичей " << k << " - го  ряда: " << loads[k];
    return 0;
}
```

После обсуждения с   `goldstar_labs` пришел к выводу переписать, поскольку первый вариант верный для  двух рядов и для крайных кирпичей

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::cin;
void setValue(const vector<double>& p1, vector<double>& p2)
{
    size_t k = p2.size();
    if (k <= 2) return;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < k - 1; ++i)
        p2[i] += (p1[i] + 1)/2;
}

int main()
{        
    unsigned ranks{}, k{};
    cin >>ranks;  // общее количество рядов
    double w{};
    vector< vector<double> >   weights;
    for (unsigned n = 1; n <= ranks; ++n) {
        vector<double> v(n, w);
        weights.emplace_back(v);
        if (n > 2 )
           setValue(weights[n - 2], weights[n - 1]);
        w = (w + 1)/2;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "вводим нужный ряд: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> k;
    k %= ranks + 1;
    std::cout << "нагрузки для кирпичей " << k << " - го  ряда:\n";
    for (double d : weights[k - 1])
        std::cout << d << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Выводить, думаю вы сами сможете в желаемом формате

Comment: это частичное решение, которое даст нагрузку на внешний слой кирпичей в пирамиде. Во внутренних слоях давление будет больше, т.к. на один кирпич внутреннего слоя будут давить два кирпича сверху

Comment: https://monosnap.com/file/XbTInOUK9c6Vp7HmWOTJrHd5uucaDg

Comment: @goldstar_labs, я об этом написал в комментарий, но в вопросе  говорится о равномерной нагрузке, поэтому ответ соответствующий

Comment: Вопрос мутный, я согласен) с одной стороны равномерно, с другой стороны "1,0=.5 2,0=.75 2,1=1.5 3,0=.875 3,1=.2.125", наверное все же неравномерно. Для неравномерного похоже на треугольник паскаля, где на каждой строке коэфф-т непонятный, пойду подумаю)

Comment: @goldstar_labs, может быть имелось ввиду что давление равномерно распределяется на следующие два кирпича. В любом случаи разобрался, и вам спасибо

Comment: спасибо. только нужно выводить нагрузку для заданного кирпича (без доп.нагрузки сверху, это как пример был). то есть функция функ(рядСверху,позиция слева) возвращает давление на кирпичь.

Comment: если k  это ряд сверху, а  n это позиция слева, то выводить нужно просто  weights[k - 1] [n - 1]  ( если отсчет рядов  и позиций начинается с 1). Вам написать как выводить, или вы все таки сами  напишете?... Если вам ответ удовлетворил, примите ответ, нажимая на галочку.  Рад помочь

Comment: @ARHovsepyan http://www.cpp.sh/ In function 'int main()': 30:7: error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'unsigned int' to binary 'operator%' 30:7: error: in evaluation of 'operator%=(double, unsigned int)'

начало - элемент 0,0.

(а в java уж как-то переведу..)

Comment: да , просто была опечатка, не там обьявил к